# Delete default shadow's points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, shadow

I am applying a color graduation for my point layer with a simple symbology.

How to delete this shadow?

[image]

It has nothing to do with the "drawing effects" option, because this is disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this really look like the "drawing effects" and as you can set several effect on the same symbol in different place I think you have disabled the "Layer" rendering drawing effects but a "symbol layer" drawing effects is still active.

See below where I highlight in green the the Symbol layer setting and in yellow the Layer setting

[image]